# Is there such a view in sql-server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Is there a view that **during the transaction** is able to show how many records have been processed? I have a transaction in which I am **inserting and deleting** data from tables. I would like to check the **current status** of the batching, i.e. how many data from a particular table have been removed or how many records have been inserted into the table **at this moment**?

Example tran:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION x
-- Some stuff
Insert <TMP_MY_TABLE>
-- Some stuff
DELETE <MY_TABLE>
COMMIT TRANSACTION x
```

SELECT like this :

```
SELECT * FROM <some system view> WHERE TABLE_NAME = <MY_TABLE>
```

I am asking for help because I can not find one myself, and that does not mean that it does not exist :)

Comment: A trigger might be one option, though this could make performance even worse, and might defeat the very purpose of trying to monitor the performance of an insert.

Comment: If it's taking long enough to where you need to monitor it, then i'd do it in batches and print out the # of rows inserted on each batch.

Comment: Performance in this case is important @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Transactions do not work that way. You can get the number of log records from `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions`, which roughly corresponds with the amount of work the transaction's doing, but is not an actual individual table row count, and so is of little use in determining how far along things are. You're probably best off using manual batches with counts you maintain yourself -- if the `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s are sufficiently big to warrant monitoring like that, that's probably a good idea anyway, to clamp down on the amount of logging generated.

Comment: Why don't you use the @@ROWCOUNT after the insert statement and after delete and keep them into some table?

Comment: Have a look at this [`SQL Server 2014 Real Time Query Monitoring`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3328/sql-server-2014-real-time-query-monitoring/)

Comment: I found answer but this is also good @M.Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this view :

```
sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

For example :

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), row_count FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'MY_TABLE'
```

`row_count` this is what I am looking for

Thank you for trying to help:)